# split SQL FULL Backups on ola hallengren maintanance solution

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren

I am using Ola Hallengren backup solution in all our environment, I have a very big Backup file which is taking 10+ hours to complete, so I am thinking to split SQL Server Full backup files.

anyone know how to split backup files in ola hallengren backup solution or else tell me if I need to create different maintenance plan only for one BIG DB

Thanks,
Ven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Scott's answer, there is also the `NumberOfFiles` parameter which would let you create multiple files under the same directory, if desired.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [Ola's `BACKUP` solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html), you can specify the `DIRECTORY` parameter with multiple directories.  Quoting from the documentation:

> **If you specify multiple directories, then the backup files are striped
>   evenly across the directories.** Specify multiple directories by using
>   the comma (,). If no directory is specified, then the SQL Server
>   default backup directory is used.